# End all metro apps windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

Is it possible to end *all* metro apps in windows 8 with C#? I don't want to kill any desktop apps, just metro apps.

I figure you'd use something like `Process.Kill()` however I don't know what arguments you'd use, if Process.Kill() even supports metro apps.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that windows would let you do that. Those apps are sandboxed on a specific runtime

Comment: They're just a windows process aren't they?

Comment: Im not sure at all. They could be hosted in a single "windows app host".

Comment: When I hit alt + tab they show as different processes

Comment: The UI doesn't define a process.. They don't show up in the task manager, which means you probably can't kill them without killing the windows hosting process.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to archive this by using WinRT/Modern UI Apps, then it is impossible because each app is hosted in its own sandbox and this behaviour would break the security layout microsoft wanted to archive with this apps.
When you use Desktop Apps, then it`s possible. The Apps show up in the taskmanager. You only have to loop through all processes, check the path to the executed file and check whether it`s saved under the WindowsApps directory. If it is, then the process is a Modern UI App, and you want to close it.
PS: The Modern UI Apps' process do not show up with their "obvious" name. For example is the "Project Spark App" called "DakotaLink.exe".
Hope this helps.